# pymysql can't access MySQL

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

Environment: macOS + anaconda 3 + Python 3.6 + MySQL 8.0

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(user='root', password='password', host='localhost', db='sample', port='3306', charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor()
```

I run it and got the error message:

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password: NO)")

The password was right, and I try to access to MySQL in terminal, it's OK.

How can I do this correctly with pymysql?

Comment: Have a look a [this](https://superuser.com/q/603026) question

Comment: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096442/using-pymysql-with-pycharm) and [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148075/1509809)

Comment: thanks but I tried and no help...