# Using pymysql with pycharm

Tags: database, pycharm, pymysql

I am trying to run a project with db synchronized with pymysql. I have not been able to start for a week due to this error. Please help me
[image]

mysql runs fine
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your connection code is written as `pymysql.connect(host="locahost", user="root", password="xxxx")` but `pymysql.connect` requires you to provide password with the named argument as "passwd". So if you change it to the following, it should work fine.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="xxx")
```

There seem to have discrepencies in the pymysql's github readme. In the example code, it says "password=", but in other source files, it says "passwd=" and I always been using "passwd" and it works fine.

Your error message also states that password is not given by `using password: NO`